# Call a function that exist on other JS file

Tags: knockout.js

In my app every view has its own JS, 
the user can click on "upload" button and a file Upload modal is showing > then he choose an image from the list > then he hit "save" button:

**fileUpload.js:**

```
  viewModel.prototype.save = function () {
        cms.closeDialog(this, this.selectedObject());
    };
```

what i am trying to achieve > when the user hit the "save" button > a thumbnail of the image will be shown in the dedicated div in **Products.html:**

```
  <div data-bind="visible: thumbnailVisible">
            <img data-bind="attr: { src: computedThumbnailUrl }, css: { 'cms-fileupload-thumbnail': isExternal }" alt="Image preview"/>
        </div>
```

- now it's working but only **after refreshing the page**.

**Products.js:**

```
 fileUpload.prototype.fileUploaded = function (fileSize, fileName, extension) {
            this.resetThumbnail();
            this.value().fileName = fileName;
            this.updateFileSize(fileSize);
            if (this.uploadCallback) {
                this.uploadCallback.call(this.context || this, fileName, extension);
            }
        };
```

From the save event in `fileUpload.js` I am trying to call `fileUploaded` function that exists in `Products.js`.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your Product.js file probably has something like this:

```
var ProductModel = {
   //code on this model

   fileUpload.prototype.fileUploaded = function (fileSize, fileName, extension) {
        this.resetThumbnail();
        this.value().fileName = fileName;
        this.updateFileSize(fileSize);
        if (this.uploadCallback) {
            this.uploadCallback.call(this.context || this, fileName, extension);
        }
    };

    //code on this model
}
```

And because of that when you try to reach that function from the outside, it's not on the current scope.
You will probably have to use the variable you set the model on `Products.js` to call your function.

Comment: in `Product.js`, `fileUploaded` function is in a function block `function(app){`, how can i call a function in `Product.js` from `fileUpload.js` page ?